# Get request parameters in alert box

Tags: javascript, parsing

I am working on parsing a specific URL contents and display request parameters in alert box.

What should I do to display request parameters in an alert box ?

Below is the code I am working

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,  initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <<script type="text/javascript">
    let url = "https://example.com/path/to/page?name=ferret&color=purple";
let params = (new URL(url)).searchParams;
params.get('name') # => "n1"
params.getAll('name') # => ["n1", "n2"]
 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> add alert('contents of alert go here'); // this line

> alert(myVar); // or this line

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
         <html lang="en">
        <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,  initial-scale=1.0">
         <title>Document</title>
        </head>
        <body>
          <script type="text/javascript">
            let url = "https://example.com/path/to/page?name=ferret&color=purple";
        let params = (new URL(url)).searchParams;
        params.get('name') # => "n1"
        params.getAll('name') # => ["n1", "n2"]
        
        myVar = 'some content';

        alert('contents of alert go here'); // this line
        alert(myVar); // or this line
         </script>
        
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I need to parse this URL and display request parameters in alert box ; https://example.com/path/to/page?name=ferret&color=purple"

Comment: @deco99 parse what you need, put it into a variable, and return the variable in alert(variable) - better though, to console.log(variable) and see the output in the browser console